# Not able to build a wheel for frozenlist

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to run a discord bot that has dependencies on poetry.

When installing poetry I encountered an error where it could not build a wheel for multidict.

This was resolved by installing latest version of Microsoft Visual C++
However it did not resolve this error of not being able to build a wheel for frozenlist.

I have tried re-installing python after installing Visual C++ which made no difference to this error,

```
Collecting frozenlist==1.3.0
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.0.tar.gz (65 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: frozenlist
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      **********************
      * Accellerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\frozenlist
      copying frozenlist\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\frozenlist
      running egg_info
      writing frozenlist.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to frozenlist.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to frozenlist.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'frozenlist\*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying frozenlist\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\frozenlist
      copying frozenlist\_frozenlist.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\frozenlist
      copying frozenlist\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\frozenlist
      running build_ext
      building 'frozenlist._frozenlist' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\frozenlist
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\wierd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\wierd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcfrozenlist/_frozenlist.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\frozenlist/_frozenlist.obj
      _frozenlist.c
      frozenlist/_frozenlist.c(7127): error C2037: left of 'f_lineno' specifies undefined struct/union '_frame'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for frozenlist
Failed to build frozenlist
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
```